# making text boxes non editable in html

Tags: html

i am trying to make a text box no editable for the users. I tried using this code and it works. Any ramifications??? I mean do u suggest the use of this code or it may cause trouble for me in future???

```
<input type="text" name="west" value="fixed value" readonly />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you shouldnt have a problem with this code as the inputs value gets submitted along with any other inputs in the form.

Make sure that you validate this on the server side as someone could send a value you are not expecting via dev tools or tools like fiddler.

I would change it to have a value. e.g readonly="readonly" so that it is valid xhtml.
The value of the readonly attribute is irrelevant and can therefore be any value.

All of the below are readonly

```html
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="readonly" />
<input type="text" readonly="true"  value="true" />
<input type="text" readonly="monkey" value="monkey" />
<input type="text" readonly="false" value="false (still readonly)" />
```

[input documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: That's only if you want valid xhtml, at the moment it's valid html and that's good enough for most people.

Answer (score 3):

You must be aware that anybody can change this to something writable using a tool like firebug.